# Running a Cryptocurrency Bot 24/7 Without a Computer

Tags: contract-development, dapps, decentralized-exchange

I've developed a cryptocurrency trading bot, but I don't want to leave my personal computer running all the time just to keep it operational. Is there a method or service that allows me to run the bot continuously without needing my computer to be on?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a method or service that allows me to run the bot continuously without needing my computer to be on?

It is a called a server. A server is a computer that is in a data center that runs 24/7.

The cheapest tier servers are called Virtual Private Servers (VPS) or a cloud server. You can rent them e.g. from OVH, Hetzner, Amazon, Google, Microsoft.

You might need to study and learn how to operate remote operating systems. This should be covered in any basic IT curriculum.